# Row Count Grouping/Row Count Grouping in report

Tags: reporting

I have a Summary Report and I need to get the % of Grouping level 2 as a percentage of Grouping Level 1.

I have tried to use combinations of this but I am wondering, if these are text fields is this possible?

Comment: question is unclear what are asking for. If you post a picture what you are trying to achieve then probably members can respond with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting from Grouping Level 2:

RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, ParentGrouping) created as a Formula field percentage - this solved the issue